# .NET - Can I use SQL code on an existing Datatable?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, vb.net

I'd like to utilize Select & Insert statements on a DataTable in VB.NET or C#.

Example:

```
Dim Results as DataTable 
Results = Select * from SourceDataTable where PlayerID < 10
```

Is anything similar to this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using .NET 3.5 then you can use [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa904594.aspx) (I don't know the VB.NET syntax, so here's C#):

```
var results = from row in SourceDataTable.AsEnumerable()
              where row.Field<int>("PlayerID") < 10
              select row;
```

It's not *exactly* the same, but certainly pretty close to "natural" SQL syntax. LINQ also has the advantage that it works on any collection type (and even directly against the database, using LINQ-to-SQL), not just DataTables.

Comment: @hamlin11: `row` is a variable to hold the 'current' row as it goes through the collection. [Field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891.aspx) is an extension method on the `DataRow` type.

Answer (score 2):

DataTables have a select method which return an array of DataRow

the filterExpression and sort paramaters take sql;

```
result = SourceDataTable.Select(" PlayerID < 10 ")
```

Answer (score 1):

For select use

```
DataTable dt ;
dt = dt.Select("PlayerID < 10");
```

in C#